# Fetch-Bulk-Collect with ForAll timing irregularities

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulkinsert

I have written a SQL query like this:

```
LOOP

FETCH cursorA
   BULK COLLECT INTO structure1 LIMIT 1000;

EXIT WHEN structure1.COUNT = 0;

FORALL i IN 1 .. structure1.COUNT
   -- do something;

--write time it took to finish loop

END LOOP;
```

I noticed that the first query fetch takes a long time to finish relative to the second, third, and further queries.

- Is this intended behaviour?
- Can someone explain what's happening behind the scene to cause this?

Comment: How much longer?

Well, the cursor has to be opened, and all the things behind the scenes have to be prepared for the execution of this bulk collect.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I should put a timing point to time how long the overhead is before it even starts running! As far as you know, the difference in timing shouldn't be expected then?

Comment: Check the execution plan for the query. There are a number of reasons why it may take a long time before it can start emitting rows; e.g. sorting, hash joins, or full table scans (where matching rows are only found later in the table).

Comment: Before the data can be fetched, the query has to be parsed and executed, so it depends on the performance of the cursor's underlying query. As @JeffreyKemp stated, check your query's execution plan, try running it as a standalone query and see how long it takes to get the first results.

Answer (score 0):

From what we know, nothing wrong with this behaviour.

The First execution of this "fetch `LIMIT 1000`" can take more time because

- it builds the execution plan for the query
- it does other preparations that will be necessary for each fetching

Moreover, depending on your db server architecture (e.g. >1 proc), while you process the result of your first fetch, the second fetch is being processed in parallel, making the second fetch ***look*** shorter (and same for the next ones too).